# How can I make a slice containing numbers divided by a period?

Tags: go

I have a standard input string, which must be made of numbers and letters, divided by the character "." (Example= as12d.fg34h).

The task is to make a new slice which contains just numbers and the character ".". I know how to get numbers :

```
for _, char := range string {
  if char >= '0' && char <= '9' {
  seq = append(seq, int(char - '0'))
}
```

The problem is this character ".", because if I try to make it int, I get the number from its position in the ascii table, but if I leave rune, it gives error (slice of int can keep just int).
So how can I get the result [12.34]?

Comment: What is the type of the result slice?

Comment: Since you store the integer value of the digits, there's a subsequent step when you convert or print this slice. Show that. You may store any value in the slice for `.` which in that last step you output as the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your problem is how to store `.` in a slice of int.
You can try to use string instead of slice of int.

```golang
func main() {
    str := "as12d.fg34h"
    seq := "" // use string instead of slice of int
    for _, char := range str {
        if char == '.' {
            seq += string(char) // covert rune to string & append
        }
        if char >= '0' && char <= '9' {
            seq += string(char)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(seq)
}
```